# Failed to find provider info for browser

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I'm on a MOOC in Coursera, and I'm trying to run an application which reads bookmarks and display them.

To do so, I need to set a Permission in the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.permissionslab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <!--  TODO - add uses-permission elements -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityLoaderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BookmarksActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_permissions" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GoToDangerousActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customization" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That prevents to get a SecurityException, However, when I try to run my application on my Android device, I get the following Error in LogCat:

```
03-02 02:58:13.579: I/Lab-Permissions(15438): Entered loadBookmarks()
03-02 02:58:13.589: W/dalvikvm(15438): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4166d498)
03-02 02:58:13.589: E/ActivityThread(15438): Failed to find provider info for browser
03-02 02:58:13.589: E/test(15438): Exception
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity.loadBookmarks(BookmarksActivity.java:59)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity.access$0(BookmarksActivity.java:50)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at course.labs.permissionslab.BookmarksActivity$1.onClick(BookmarksActivity.java:32)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17150)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
03-02 02:58:13.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15438):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't what's going on, it seems that it doesn't find a provider, but I have two browsers so i don't get it.

This is my BookmarksActivy code, please ignore the "Dangerous Activity" which invokes another stuff.

```
package course.labs.permissionslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BookmarksActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Lab-Permissions";

    static final String[] projection = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks_activity);

        Button getBookmarksButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_bookmarks_button);
        getBookmarksButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                loadBookmarks();

            }
        });

        Button goToDangerousActivityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_dangerous_activity_button);
        goToDangerousActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startGoToDangerousActivity();

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadBookmarks() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered loadBookmarks()");

        String text = "";

        Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);

        query.moveToFirst();
        while (query.moveToNext()) {

            text += query.getString(query
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            text += "\n";
            text += query.getString(query
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            text += "\n\n";

        }

        TextView box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        box.setText(text);

        Log.i(TAG, "Bookmarks loaded");
    }

    private void startGoToDangerousActivity() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startGoToDangerousActivity()");

        Intent dangerous = new Intent(BookmarksActivity.this,GoToDangerousActivity.class);
            startActivity(dangerous);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried by copying and pasting your code, that works fine on my side, no `Exception` no any `Logcat`, then why this does not work for you??

Comment: I met the same too, do you solve this? How?I think this may vary on devices.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, your device runs Chrome, rather than the AOSP browser. If so, instead of Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, use:

```
Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks")
```

i.e.,

```
Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks"),
                projection, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if browser settings have anything to do with your issue. Go to the "App info" screen for the preferred browser on your device. In the "Launch By Default" tap the "Clear defaults" button and then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

download aosp installer from google play store and install browser . your device may not have default browser that comes with Rom.